# How to make a song loop/how to make a loop command

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

So I use discord.js and I've been successful with other commands but not a loop command for my discord bot.A loop command where it plays the song repeatedly until it the loop command is executed again. If you need me to add somethings in just let me know because I am new to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Can you please add more description. What do you mean with loop command?

Comment: A loop command where it  plays the song repeatedly until it the loop command is executed again.

Comment: @Monkeyyy11 ^^^

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to set up a queue system.

Secondly, once a music queue is completed/finished, just shift the queue and it will play the very same music again.

Thirdly, to create a loop command, just place the shift method inside a command.

For example:

```
if (message.content === 'loop') {
   // shift code here
   // message.channel.send('Loop has been turned on.')
}
```